# Faster way of iterate through xarray and dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance, loops, python-xarray

Im new to python and dont know all the aspects.

I want to loop through a `dataframe` (2D) and assign some of those values to an `xarray` (3D).
The coordinates of my xarray are company ticker symbols (1), financial variables (2) and daily dates (3).
The columns of the `dataframe` for each company are some of the same financial variables as in the `xarray` and the index is made up of quarterly dates.

My goal is to take an already generated `dataframe` for each company and look for a value that is in the column of a certain variable and the row of a certain date and assign it to its corresponding spot in the `xarray`.

Since some dates are not going to be in the index of the `dataframe` (only has 4 dates per calendar year), I want to assign either a 0 to that spot on the `xarray` or the value from the previous date on the `xarray` if that value is also not 0.
I have tried to do it using nested for loops, but it takes around 20 seconds to go through all the dates in just one variable.

My date list if made up of around 8000 dates, the variable list has around 30 variables and the company list is around 800 companies.
If I were to loop around all of that it would take me several days to complete the nested for loops.
Is there a faster way to assign these values to the `xarray`? My guess is something similar to `iterrows()` or `iteritems()` but in `xarray`.
Heres is a sample code of my program with shorter lists for the companies and variables:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import time

start_time = time.time()

# We create the df. This is aun auxiliary made-up df. Its a shorter version of the real df. 
# The real df I want to use is much larger and comes from an external method.
cols = ['cashAndCashEquivalents', 'shortTermInvestments', 'cashAndShortTermInvestments', 'totalAssets',
        'totalLiabilities', 'totalStockholdersEquity', 'netIncome', 'freeCashFlow']
rows = []
for year in range(1989, 2020):
    for month, day in zip([3, 6, 9, 12], [31, 30, 30, 31]):
        rows.append(date(year, month, day))
a = np.random.randint(100, size=(len(rows), len(cols)))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a, columns=cols)
df.insert(column='date', value=rows, loc=0)
# This is just to set the date format so that I can later look up the values
for item, i in zip(df.iloc[:, 0], range(len(df.iloc[:, 0]))):
    df.iloc[i, 0] = datetime.strptime(str(item), '%Y-%m-%d')
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# Coordinates for the xarray:
companies = ['AAPL']  # This is actually longer (around 800 companies), but for the sake of the question, it is limited to just one company.
variables = ['totalAssets', 'totalLiabilities', 'totalStockholdersEquity']  # Same as with the companies (around 30 variables).
first_date = date(1998, 3, 25)
last_date = date.today() + timedelta(-300)
dates = pd.date_range(start=first_date, end=last_date).tolist()

# We create a zero xarray, so that we can later fill it up with values:
z = np.zeros((len(companies), len(variables), len(dates)))
ds = xr.DataArray(z, coords=[companies, variables, dates],
                  dims=['companies', 'variables', 'dates'])

# We assign values from the df to the ds
for company in companies:
    for variable in variables:
        first_value_found = False
        for date in dates:
            # Dates in the df are quarterly dates and dates in the ds are daily dates.
            # We start off by looking for a certain date in the df. If we dont find it, we give it the value 0 in the ds
            # If we do find it, we assign it the value found in the df and tell it that the first value has been found
            # Now that the first value has been found, when we dont find a value in the df, instead of giving it a value of 0, we give it the value of the last date.
            if first_value_found == False:
                try:
                    ds.loc[company, variable, date] = df.loc[date, variable]
                    first_value_found = True
                except:
                    ds.loc[company, variable, date] = 0
            else:
                try:
                    ds.loc[company, variable, date] = df.loc[date, variable]
                except:
                    ds.loc[company, variable, date] = ds.loc[company, variable, date + timedelta(-1)]

print("My program took", time.time() - start_time, "to run")
```

The main problem is with the for loops, as I have tested these loops on separate files and these seem to be what takes the most time.

Answer (score 1):

One possible strategy is to loop over the actual index of the DataFrame, rather than all *possible* indices

```py
avail_dates = df.index
for date in avail_dates:
    # Copy the data
```

That should already reduce the number of iterations by quite a bit. You still have to make sure all the blanks are filled, so you'd do something like

```py
    da.loc[company, variables, date:] = df.loc[date, variables]
```

That's right, you can index into DataArray and DataFrame with lists. (Also I wouldn't use `ds` as a variable name for something from `xarray` other than a `DataSet`)

---

What you probably want to use, though, is [pandas.DataFrame.reindex()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html).

If I understand what you're trying to do, this should more or less do the trick (not tested)

```py
complete_df = df.reindex(dates, method='pad', fill_value=0)
da.loc[company, variables, :] = complete_df.loc[:, variables].T
```